# MODULE_NOT_FOUND error in Docker-Swarm for NodeJS Application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I wrote a simple Hello World App in NodeJS and tried to deploy it on a single-node Docker-Swarm Cluster.
However, on the (one) master node, the command

`docker service create --with-registry-auth --name test-backend --env APP_HOST=0.0.0.0 --env APP_PORT=3000 --network custom-overlay-net registry.example.com/<user>/<image>:latest test-backend`

yields to the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
   throw err;
   ^

 Error: Cannot find module '/home/node/test-backend'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
 }
```

What I wonder about is that when I run the image as a standalone docker container, or via docker-compose, everything works as expected.
**Also, when I overwrite the entrypoint in the 'docker service create'-command with `--entrypoint "/bin/bash -c \"node ./index.js\""`, everything works fine.**

Contents of the index.js:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});
if (!process.env.APP_HOST) {
        console.error('Please specify the APP_HOST environment variable');
}

if (!process.env.APP_PORT) {
    console.error('Please specify the APP_PORT environment variable');
}

server.listen(parseInt(process.env.APP_PORT), process.env.APP_HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${process.env.APP_HOST}:${process.env.APP_PORT}/`);
});
```

Contents of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.16.1

WORKDIR /home/node/

# copy all resources
COPY . .

CMD ["node", "./index.js"]
```

File structure:

- index.js
- Dockerfile
- package.json

Of course I could simply just override the entrypoint to get things working, but I'd like to understand why using the default entrypoint script causes problems here.

I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does `test-backend` correspond to? Is it part of you project?

Comment: It's the name of the npm project and the container, so nothing special there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `test-backend` as argument, given that you have specified the service with `--name`.

Following should suffice:

```
docker service create --with-registry-auth --name test-backend --env APP_HOST=0.0.0.0 --env APP_PORT=3000 --network custom-overlay-net registry.example.com/<user>/<image>:latest
```

---

> Note: As @Dmytro Sirant pointed out, when `test-backend` is appended - its taken as `CMD ["test-backend"]` which would lead to the above error.

Comment: Just a liitle more info what happened. Last "test-backend" in your command translates to the CMD and instead of run CMD from your Dockerfile it's running ENTRYPOINT of the image you are using in FROM with CMD ["test-backend"]

Comment: Thank you for the explaination - that worked. I didn't expect the answer to be that simple.